# how to create hbase table with multiple columns family on HDP hortonworks?

Tags: hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

i'm pretty new with HDP and i want to create an hbase table with multiple columns, and load data from an an csv file as below

[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F9E3.png)

as u can see, i have per example column family "informations personnelles" that contains multiples columns such as "nom" "prenom" and so on.

so my questions is:
 - how to create table hbase with java api on hdp sandbox?
 - how to load data from my csv file?

ps: i tried to create table but i dont know how to run it on sandbox? where to put my java class? do i need to configure something?

here is my code

```
    import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

public class CreateTable {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      // Instantiating configuration class
      Configuration con = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        con.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
        con.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "hortonworks.hbase.vm");
        con.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");
        System.out.println("HBase is running!");

      // Instantiating HbaseAdmin class
      HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(con);

      // Instantiating table descriptor class
      HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor = new
      TableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf("competence"));

      // Adding column families to table descriptor
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Infos_collaborateur"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Infos_Rh"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Savoir_faire"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Savoir_etre"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Langues"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Java:Developpement/Librairies/API/Frameworks/CMS"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("PHP/Frameworks"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Techno_Web/Frameworks"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Autres"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("ERP:Language/Outils"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Mobile:natif"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Mobile:Cross"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Infographie/creas"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Outils_de_developpement/Software"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Analytics"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Outils_Microsoft"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Developpements/Librairies"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("BaseDeDonnees/FluxDeDonnees"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Windows:SystemeDexploitation/serveur"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("AutresOS"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Plateforms"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Serveur_web_parametrage"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Serveur_Application_parametrage"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Integration/fonctionnel"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Outils_de_conception/de_gestion_projet"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("AMOA"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Experience"));   
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Interventions"));            

      // Execute the table through admin
      admin.createTable(tableDescriptor);
      System.out.println(" Table created ");
   }
}
```

thanks an advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run java program from your local machine to connect to sandbox hbase and zookeeper, then you need to do port forwarding for 2181 port in sandbox settings > network > advanced > port forwarding. Giving any Name like zk, Protocol:TCP, Hist IP:127.0.0.1, Host Port:2181, Guest Port: 2181. Then in your program set the conf as below and run the program:

```
con.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
con.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "127.0.0.1");
```

In your java program, you can read csv file using scanner api as for reference http://www.journaldev.com/2335/read-csv-file-java-scanner and store data using java hbase api to store data as for reference https://autofei.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/java-example-code-using-hbase-data-model-operations/

Other option is to send your file and java program jar to sandbox and run there. To copy or ssh to sandbox you need to do port forwarding as well like as above giving Host Port:2222, Guest Port: 22

Hope this helps you...